# How to make PHP store information untill purchase is complete?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a form that is for customizing a YouTube background.

anyways. I coded this in HTML and when you hit submit, it sends the information to a PHP file that processes the information and sends it as an e-mail.

This works fine but I need to set it up so it doesn't send me the e-mail until they purchase it.

How I want it to work is like this.

They fill out the form and click submit, then they are redirected to the URL of my item on PayPal. (If that doesn't work, there is a buy now button on the PHP site) Either way. They end up on PayPal and purchase the item. Once they purchase it, I will receive the email with the details they requested on the form. If they cancel it, I won't get the email and give it to them free.

I was wondering if the option PayPal gives to show a site once they complete the purchase would help. It could link to another PHP file possibly? For example, if the first PHP file stores the information and the second PHP that PayPal redirects to will tell it to release the data? I'm not sure.

Comment: Careful of posting PHP code which contains personal information. Just dully noted since Dropbox Amazon S3 backed up does not allow server code.

Comment: You could store info in the current session so that when the user is redirected back you can get it, or you could generate some random key, store order info in the database along with the key, then use paypal redirect back url to return from checkout with the key and extract order info from database.

Comment: I'm not using Dropbox to host the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay. I figured it out. All I needed to do was make a PayPal Buy Now button and take some code from it.
Then you just put all of the form tags you already have under it.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has a callback feature called Instant Payment notification. They have great examples of using this feature also. basically you would not have the email functions in the sendYT.php you would put them in a php file PayPal would call. Here is more information on it: https://www.paypal.com/ipn

I sugest joined the PayPal developer network too if your going to be doing any amount of work with PayPal as it can be very complicated

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to recieve the information vhey enter on my form?